# Notice: Undefined index: category

Tags: php, indexing, undefined, categories

**Notice: Undefined index: category in /opt/lampp/htdocs/content/cron/check_deposits.php on line 18**

```
$deposits=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `deposits`");
while ($dp=mysql_fetch_array($deposits)) {
  $received=0;
  $txid='';
  $txs=$wallet->listtransactions('',2000);
  $txs=array_reverse($txs);
  foreach ($txs as $tx) {
  if($tx['category']!='receive') continue;
  if ($tx['confirmations']<1) continue;
    if ($tx['address']!=$dp['address']) continue;
    $received=$tx['amount'];
    $txid=$tx['txid'];
    break;
```

This is how it came out of the box. I contacted support about the issue and they told me to make sure I was using PHP 5.3.1  which I am. What is wrong with this?

***Here is a link to the full code:***
http://diceking.tk/deposit.txt

Answer (score 0):

You need to change from

```
if($tx['category']!='receive') continue;
```

to

```
if(isset($tx['category']) && $tx['category']!='receive') continue;
```

Comment: Now I am getting

Notice: Undefined index: confirmations in /opt/lampp/htdocs/content/cron/check_deposits.php on line 19

Answer (score 0):

Check if the variables are set.
So, for the error about confirmations, you can use this:

```
if(isset($tx['confirmations']) && $tx['confirmations'] < 1) continue;
```

For the error about the undefined index: Category you can use this:

```
if(isset($tx['category']) && $tx['category']!='receive') continue;
```

I hope I'll helped you.
If this helped, please vote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

***Notice: Undefined index: amount in /opt/lampp/htdocs/content/cron/check_deposits.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined index: txid in /opt/lampp/htdocs/content/cron/check_deposits.php on line 22
Notice: Undefined index: amount in /opt/lampp/htdocs/content/cron/check_deposits.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined index: txid in /opt/lampp/htdocs/content/cron/check_deposits.php on line 22***

Ahh so we have made it this far.. I tried this trick and it hated me for it:

```
if(isset($received=$tx['amount']) && $received=$tx['amount']) continue;
```